# How to run a Tmux command across all panes in a single or multiple sessions?

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, tmux

I sometimes want to run a Tmux command across all panes in a single or multiple sessions to e.g. clean up my working environment.

An example would be to execute this Tmux command:

```
# Clear screen
bind M-l send-keys -R \; clear-history \; send-keys C-l \; display "█▓░ clear"
```

I know of the `synchronize-panes` window option, but AFAIK it only synchronize panes in the current window, and not all panes in all sessions:

```
# Synchronize panes (toggle option)
bind C-s setw synchronize-panes \; display "█▓░ synchronize (#{?synchronize-panes,on,off})"
```

Is there a way to run a Tmux command across all panes in a single session or multiple sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script I wrote to do this. Save it as `tmux-sendall` (`chmod +x tmux-sendall`):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
    current=$(tmux display -p "#S")
    echo "usage: tmux-sendall SESSION [COMMAND]"
    if [[ -n $current ]]; then
        echo "current session: $current"
    fi
    exit 1
else
    session="$1"
fi

if [[ -n $2 ]]; then
    message="$2"
else
    read -p "send cmd to session $session$ " message
    if [[ -z $message ]]; then exit 1; fi
fi

function sendwindow() {
    # $1=target, $2=command
    tmux setw -t $1 synchronize-panes
    tmux send-keys -lt "$1" "$2"
    tmux send-keys -t "$1" "Enter"
    tmux setw -t $1 synchronize-panes off
}

export -f sendwindow
tmux list-windows -t $session | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -I{} bash -c "sendwindow '$session:{}' '$message'"
```

It lists the windows for the given session and then executes the `sendwindow` function for each one.

You can customize the `sendwindow` function with tmux commands if you want it to do something else.

Example, assuming you have a session named `1`:

```
tmux-sendall 1 "echo hello world"
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I execute my key-binding above, `M-l`? Would I need to run your script as `tmux-sendall 1 'send-keys -R \; clear-history \; send-keys C-l \; display "█▓░ clear"'`, or could I run it with `M-l` as second argument?

Comment: You threw me off because you were using send-keys. This function is for sending keys (as if you were typing into the panes). If you simply want to execute a tmux command you can run it without all of this - see the -t option: `clear-history [-t target-pane]`

Comment: Ahh, I see. So there is no way to say to Tmux: "**run my `M-l` key-binding in all sessions**"? I have tried your script with `C-a M-l`, but it doesn't seem that `send-keys` can run key-bindings?

Comment: My script disables these because it is meant to send text. You can try to remove the `-l` flag from send-keys, change `-lt` to `-t`.